# Movie, classic comedy about two girls, one of them becomes a ghost

Tags: identify-this-movie

This is a movie I've seen a long while ago on TCM. What I remember from it is:

- it was a classic movie, circa 1950s - 1960s
- it was about two girls, who were friends, and they were in some mansion at some point
- one of them is murdered, and becomes a ghost, which is sometimes immaterial (can pass through things), but sometimes it can interact with them
- the girl who's a ghost is invisible except to her friend, who can see her
- it was a comedy, and sort of a murder mistery, as the ghost tries to reveal her murderer to the others

Comment: Sounds a bit like [Topper Returns](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0034303/combined), but it's from the 40s and it's a guy that can see her, not her friend (though there *is* a friend called Ann that she's trying to protect, and there's also a mansion).

Comment: @Walt thanks, that's it. Can you please write this as an answer, so I can accept it ?

Comment: Le retour de Topper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comedy [Topper Returns](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0034303/combined) from 1941.

> Topper is once again tormented by a fun-loving spirit. This time, it's Joan Blondell, who was accidentally murdered while vacationing at the [mansion] of her wealthy friend, Ann Carrington (Landis), the intended victim. With Topper's help, Joan sets out to find her killer with the expected zany results.

The full movie is available on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/Topper_Returns_41). Here's the trailer: